# Wordpress picture's colour changes after selecting

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

While adding a product, when I select a product picture, it's color changes. It does not happen with all the images but with some of them. [![Real image][1]][1] [![this is what becomes of it!][2]][2]

Color changes in wp-admin on the Add New Product page so, I think it is not due to any custom CSS. Plus, I am not using any custom CSS as well.
I am using Woocommerce with Elementor.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRxn0.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiDPd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with wordpress which desaturizes images. To fix, try steps in this post:

[https://soliloquywp.com/how-to-fix-the-image-desaturation-issue-in-wordpress-with-photoshop/#:~:text=When%20you%20create%20an%20image,slide%20might%20loose%20its%20sharpness](https://soliloquywp.com/how-to-fix-the-image-desaturation-issue-in-wordpress-with-photoshop/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20an%20image,slide%20might%20loose%20its%20sharpness)

Comment: It worked :D I just exported the image in sRGB from Lightroom and it did the job. Thanks a lot.